# Using Azure Data Factory 2, I can not copy containers that have a large number of blobs

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm having a problem with Azure Data Factory V2, where containers with a large number of blobs are not copied. One pipeline run went almost 75 hours before it finally failed with an error.

```
Activity Copy1 failed: ErrorCode=FailedStorageOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A storage operation failed with the following error
 &apos;Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.&apos;.,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection:
 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,''Type=System.IO.IOException,Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.,Source=System,''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,Message=An
 existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host,Source=System,'
```

**Additional Details**

- 5 Pipelines each with 1 copy activity (3 succeed, 2 fail).

  - Using auto for parallel copy and DMUs
  - skip incompatible rows
  - no staging
- Source data set uses a SAS key for an Azure Storage Account.

  - The storage account is configured for RA-GRS, and I am attempting to read from the secondary (read access) location.
  - Using the recursive and binary file options.
- Destination data set uses a SAS key for an Azure Storage Account.

  - The storage account is located in the same data center as the Source data set (storage account's RA secondary).
  - Using the preserve hierarchy option
- Source and destination are both US South Central

I have tried 5 different source containers, 3 were successful while 2 failed. The commonality between the 2 that failed seems to be the number of blobs in the containers. One container has over 30 million blobs in the root. I don't know the number in the other container, but it's over 1 TB made up of small files (15 KB each) organized into sub folders 2 levels deep. I've tried to reproduce the folder structure the best I could.

- Container 1 (Success)

  - {Guid-Folder-Name}/Blob.jpg
  - 65GB, 63,555 files copied
- Container 2 (Success)

  - Folder/guid-file-name
  - 209GB, 2,724,023 files copied
- Container 3 (Success)

  - Folder/{Folder}/blob.txt
  - filtered to *.txt
  - 606MB, 687,559 files copied
- Container 4 (Failed)

  - Folder/{IntId-FolderName}/blob
  - filtered to *.json
  - more than 62,500,000 total files, filtered to *.json would be 10% of that
- Container 5 (failed)

  - Folder/guid-file-name
  - more than 30 million blobs

With container 4, I tried a source with a filter and without, and neither worked. I then changed the source to be a more specific path (Folder/1234) that had ~100,000 blobs, and it copied just fine with a filter specified. Since I have had a successful copy using both filtered and unfiltered sources, and with varying path structures (containers 1-3), it seems that the problem is the number of blobs.